# How to create .vue file in MVC project in Visual studio 2013

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, vue.js

I want to use Vue.js in my MVC project.
I am using Visual studio 2013.

I have added the reference file and also added the demo code shown up in the Vue.js documentation. I am able to run and result is displayed successfully.
Now I am trying to add .Vue file in my code.

Visual Studio 2013 does not have built in template for the same. Can anyone suggest how to create .Vue file in Visual studio 2013

Comment: for visual studio 2015 is available link :-  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SilentBedlam.VueJS-jQuery-BootstrapProjectTemplate

Comment: I do not recommend the above link, there's literally no need or reason to be using jQuery when you are using a library that already handles the DOM manipulation. I would use the official tooling for this https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli

Comment: Is there any way to use vue.js components by coding in .cshtml and .js files in MVC project instead of .Vue file?